# Problema com multiplicação de matrizes em python

Tags: python-3.x

Alguém pode me dizer qual é o problema com esse código ? (sou iniciante).

```py
import random
def mult():
    num_l1, num_c1 = len(mat1), len(mat1[0])
    num_l2, num_c2 = len(mat2), len(mat2[0])
    for i in range(num_l1):
        resp.append([])
        for j in range(num_c2):
            resp[i].append(0)
            for m in range(num_c1):
                resp[i][j] += mat1[i][m] * mat2[m][j]
    return resp
mat1 = []
mat2 = []
resp = []
for i in range(3):
    mat1.append([0] * 3)
for i in range(3):
    mat2.append([0] * 3)
for i in range(len(mat1)):
    for j in range(len(mat1)):
        mat1[i][j] = random.randint(0, 9)
for i in range(len(mat1)):
    for j in range(len(mat1)):
        mat2[i][j] = random.randint(0, 9)

mult()
```

Comment: Qual o erro? ...

Comment: O código simplesmente não executa, ou aparenta que nada acontece

Answer (score 1):

Seu código não imprime nada por isso você está achando que ele não faz nada, fiz algumas modificações no seu código:

- Seu método não recebe nenhum parâmetro passe as matrizes por parâmetro `def mult(mat1, mat2)`;
- Chame o método dentro de um print assim você pode ver os resultados `print(mult(mat1, mat2))`

_

```
import random
def mult(mat1, mat2):
    num_l1, num_c1 = len(mat1[0]), len(mat1[1])
    num_l2, num_c2 = len(mat2[0]), len(mat2[1])
    for i in range(num_l1):
        resp.append([])
        for j in range(num_c2):
            resp[i].append(0)
            for m in range(num_c1):
                resp[i][j] += mat1[i][m] * mat2[m][j]
    return resp
mat1 = []
mat2 = []
resp = []
for i in range(3):
    mat1.append([0] * 3)
for i in range(3):
    mat2.append([0] * 3)
for i in range(len(mat1)):
    for j in range(len(mat1)):
        mat1[i][j] = random.randint(0, 9)
for i in range(len(mat1)):
    for j in range(len(mat1)):
        mat2[i][j] = random.randint(0, 9)

print(mult(mat1, mat2))
```